# How can we search a particular directory for files in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

Here i know the source folder path.But i want to search a particular folder like "MANAGERS" in the list of directories for files.Could we do this type of operation in C# Windows Application?Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(mySourceFolder);
DirectoryInfo[] diArr = di.GetDirectories();

foreach (DirectoryInfo dri in diArr)
{
    if(dri.Name.ToUpperInvariant() == "MANAGERS")
    {
        FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles(); // get a list of files in directory
    }
}
```

Comment: But here i dont know where the "MANAGER" folder is ?

Comment: @programmer4programming - If you don't know where a folder is, how do you expect to search it?

Comment: @programmer4programming - _what_ folder name? Where is the "MANAGERS" folder supposed to be then? See my updated answer. I am guessing at what you need, however.